# How to get list length?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list of items and other empty list.. when I click on an item I send it to the empty list and I returns that it has an item in.. but when I called that list after adding items in it returns length = 0. what can I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjANC.png)

Comment: Try debugging it and step through each line and watch what happens to your list.

Comment: i did it but when active next screen the list return length = 0